# Magento 2, call table from database

Tags: magento2, php, database, table

I can not find a way to retrieve the value of a table from the database. With Magento 1.9 you used the Mage class but now you can no longer use with Magento 2.0.2.

How to do?

Comment: can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure, I created four table in my database and are four type of quantity (qty, qty2, qty3, qty4). Of course the qty table already exists, I have created the other three. Now I wish I could recall the value of every single table in the database and to display them in the product details of my site. How can I write to recall them?

Comment: Are you talking about product attributes when you are referring "qty", "qty2", "qty3", "qty4", means form fields of your product create form ?